# Does primary constructor in C# generates init only or protected set property?

Tags: c#, rider

Consider the following code:

```
public enum TransactionType{Foo,Bar}

public abstract record Transaction
{
    public TransactionType Type { get; }

    protected Transaction(TransactionType type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}

public record InheritedTransactionBarOnly: Transaction
{
    public InheritedTransactionBarOnly(): base(TransactionType.Bar){}
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var iWantThis = new InheritedTransactionBarOnly();
        //var iDontWantThis = new InheritedTransactionBarOnly{Type = TransactionType.Foo}; // this shouldn't be possible
    }
}
```

Rider is suggesting to convert to a primary constructor:
[image: rider suggestion]

but I do believe this is wrong, as this will allow for `Type` to be set during the initialization of the inherited record:

```
var inheritedTransaction = new InheritedTransactionBarOnly
{
   Type = TransactionType.Foo // This code compiles only after Rider suggested change, but not before
}
```

Is my understanding is wrong or it is just a bug in Rider?

P.S. This is what Transaction looks like after Rider's conversion:

```
public abstract record Transaction(TransactionType Type)
{
}
```

Comment: _"as this will allow for `Type` to be set during the initialization of the inherited record."_ - what do you mean by that?

Comment: what code do you get after it has been converted to constructor?

Comment: Have fixed the question with regards to the comments

Comment: I deleted my comment, I was wrong. Indeed it does look like properties defined via record ctor params **are** `{ get; init; }` auto-properties...

Comment: @CodeCaster I do not want this property to be set outside of inherited classes

Comment: @JohnLBevan It does not seem to be the case: see the comment in my edited question

Comment: @CodeCaster please take a look at the comment: this code only compiles after I perform Rider suggestion

Comment: @CodeCaster It's a problem because it makes a mockery of the principle of combining constructors with immutable properties to establish _state invariants_: it allows any consumer to subvert any constructor-level validation because they can simply overwrite a property to a new, possibly invalid, value after the ctor has run.

Comment: @Dai I just had the same realization as you; this introduces an `init` modifier, apparently?

Comment: Apparently it does, and Rider seems to be overzealous?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgAQFMB2BXAWwwBUAnAQxwGdyBjAFwEsB7HYgTwActkBvZDIIwAxZswA0AoQCFypZAF9kqTKSy1mpYCQrU6TVgAoylGgxZsuWElYCUfRcqSw0DpEIywYUwf3cehEz1zVgx6AA8cOAwAXgwcLAB3HVN9C2NdMwNLbgA6UWZbAG4MAHpSjAB5AGkfALqPIKyLMMiYWPiklODsjNSQnKxc2VJbMtKGoT8AmZtuDqa01g48gsnBBSK6pSQFIA===

Comment: @JohnLBevan That doesn't change the fact the property is `{ get; init; }` though.

Comment: Sorry - I see the issue now... I've editted the question to make it clearer by providing a situation in which it makes a practical difference.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cGFyI5, you are correct

Comment: The primary constructors added by C# 12 for types other than records don't generate any properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a few test cases to show the difference between how `record`s are built. The following is just for class records, I'm not sure if the same is true for struct records.

Starting with your example, `SomeProperty { get; }` this means the property can only be set during construction, not from `new { SomeProperty  = ... }` code. But record primary constructor (the refactor suggestion) declares properties `{get; init;}` by default, which allows setting in `new ...` blocks. However, note that you *can* redefine properties inside the declaration; see the `AltRecord` record below. Perhaps this is more concise...

See [record reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) in the section "If the generated auto-implemented property definition isn't what you want" ...

---

So to answer your question, yes, this seems like a mistake in the refactor, because behavior is not the same. Here is some code to show the differences.

```cs
public abstract record GetOnlyExample
{
    // Readonly property (cannot set in new { SomeProperty = ... } )
    public int SomeProperty { get; }

    // Property can only be set once, from protected constructor.
    protected GetOnlyExample(int someProperty)
    {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }
}

public record ConcreteGetOnlyExample : GetOnlyExample
{
    // Concrete implementation, can only set SomeProperty through base constructor.
    public ConcreteGetOnlyExample() : base(1) { }
}

public abstract record GetInitExample
{
    // Readonly property, allow in init (can set in new { SomeProperty = ... } )
    public int SomeProperty { get; init; }

    // Property can only be set during construction, or init.
    protected GetInitExample(int someProperty)
    {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }
}

public record ConcreteGetInitExample : GetInitExample
{
    // Concrete implementation, can only set SomeProperty during init/construction.
    public ConcreteGetInitExample() : base(1) { }
}

// Primary constructor, creates: public int SomeProperty { get; init; }
public abstract record PrimaryConstructor(int SomeProperty)
{
}

public record ConcretePrimaryConstructor : PrimaryConstructor
{
    // Concrete implementation, can only set SomeProperty during init/construction.
    public ConcretePrimaryConstructor() : base(1) { }
}

// Primary constructor, creates: public int SomeProperty { get; init; }
public abstract record AltRecord(int SomeProperty)
{
    // redefine SomeProperty to be readonly (no init)
    public int SomeProperty { get; } = SomeProperty;
}

public record ConcreteAltRecord : AltRecord
{
    public ConcreteAltRecord() : base(1) { }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // compile error: not allowed during init:
        // ConcreteGetOnlyExample aaa = new ConcreteGetOnlyExample() { SomeProperty = 5 };

        // can set during init:
        ConcreteGetInitExample bbb = new ConcreteGetInitExample() { SomeProperty = 5 };

        // implicit init created through primary constructor:
        ConcretePrimaryConstructor ccc = new ConcretePrimaryConstructor() { SomeProperty = 8 };

        // compile error: SomeProperty was redefined as `get` only, can't set during init
        //ConcreteAltRecord ddd = new ConcreteAltRecord() { SomeProperty = 9 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I saw this ` public int SomeProperty { get; } = SomeProperty;` but I thought it would be some recursive craziness and just did not even try it, I will now use it